# How can I get a flattened list of types of members of a class

Tags: c++14, compile-time

I need to do some compile-time code analysis based on types of class members.
I found a nice libabry (magic_get) allowing to iterate the members of a class instance. I'd need to do something similar but only for types (so that it works at compile time)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/pfr/flat.hpp>
#include <type_traits>

struct PtrA  { char *s;  int a; };
struct NoPtrB{ int b; };
struct C     { int c; PtrA a; NoPtrB b; };

template<typename T>
constexpr bool has_pointer(T&&var)
{
    bool ret = false;
    boost::pfr::flat_for_each_field(var,
       [&ret](auto& field) noexcept
       {
            if( std::is_pointer<typename std::decay<decltype(field)>::type>::value)
                ret = true;
       }
    );
    return ret;
}
int main()
{
    //static_assert(has_pointer<C>(),"has_pointer"); // <-- I'd like to have working at compile time
    std:: cout << "Has pointer = "<< has_pointer(C()) << std::endl;
    std:: cout << "Has pointer = "<< has_pointer(NoPtrB()) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: C++ is currently lacking reflection, so to "iterate" over types will require additional instrumentation of those types on your part. Also, please provide some sample code for your use case.

Comment: I added an example of how this could be used

Comment: I see. What you want is impossible in vanilla C++. You must instrument your structs with additional information (perhaps via traits classes) if you wish to be able to do something like this. But, then at that point, you already know which members are pointers so the problem is moot.

Comment: It seems to be that this library (magic_get) is already doing what I need
and event more than that,  and since it deals not only with types but also with the values, it cannot be used at compile time. Maybe it is possible that this code could be simplified to only generate a type list, and that is why I posted my question.

Comment: `magic_get` is a miracle library that simulates a lot of reflection pretty nicely, but is still limited by the language. (Also if I recall correctly it depends on some technically undefined behavior that is subject to break)